# Cannot update UI in main thread with didSet swift

Tags: swift, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to update UILabel and UIImageView in main thread but its not working.

I have two ViewControllers(I'll call them ChooseCountryVC and DisplayCountryVC here) and in ChooseCountryVC, user can choose a country they like and in DisplayCountryVC I want to display the country's name in label and country's flag in imageView.

Basic process flow is below.

1. Hit "Choose a country" button in DisplayCountryVC
2. Present ChooseCountryVC which is basically a tableView of all countries and user can choose a country
3. When user choose a country, set property called "countryCode" in DisplayCountryVC and dismiss ChooseCountryVC to go back to DisplayCountryVC
4. In didSet function on "countryCode" in DisplayCountryVC, add UI update process to main thread.

Code example related to this matter is below.

●ChooseCountryVC

```
       // when user has chosen a country and dismiss this VC
        let displayCountryVC = DisplayCountryVC()
        displayCountryVC.countryCode = self.chosenCountryCode
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // go back to DisplayCountryVC
```

●DisplayCountryVC

```
 var countryCode: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let countryCode = countryCode else {return}
        let countryName = self.getCountryName(with: countryCode) // this function provides countryName with no problem
        let flagImage = self.getFlag(with: countryCode) // this function provides flag image with no problem
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageView.image = flagImage 
            self.label.text = countryName
            print("label's text is", self.label.text) // somehow, this prints out country's name correctly in console but apparently UI has not been updated at all
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody knows whats wrong with my codes or need more information, please let me know.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not necessary here. You are still in the main thread when you assign `displayCountryVC.countryCode`. How do you present your DisplayCountryVC? Are you performing `segue`? Make sure `flagImage` and `countryName` is not nil

Comment: @tuyen Thank you for your comment. That's what I thought at first so i wrote a code without DispatchQueue.main.async but it didnt work so i added it. Also, DisplayVC is the initial view controller and when a user hit a button in the VC, i present ChooseCountryVC programmatically with present function. I made sure that flagImage and countryName is not nil but still its not showing in the view.

Comment: So `didSet` was not executed if there is no `DispatchQueue.main.async`? And why do you `dismiss` `ChooseCountryVC` after presenting `DisplayCountryVC`. Is there a reason?

Comment: @tuyenle didSet gets executed without `DispatchQueue.main.async ` and if i print the text of the label in didSet closure, it prints correct string in the console but not on the view

Comment: if it prints a correct string in the console then what text do you get in the view?

Comment: @tuyenle it shows nothing in the view but i figured out how to deal with this problem with the answer below. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 // when user has chosen a country and dismiss this VC
        let displayCountryVC = DisplayCountryVC()
        displayCountryVC.countryCode = self.chosenCountryCode
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // go back to DisplayCountryVC
```

Here you init a new view controller and set the value to it.

Your chosenCountryCode is set to the NEW view controller rather than your original DisplayCountryVC.

After your ChooseCountryVC dismissed, you go back to your original DisplayCountryVC. This new DisplayCountryVC is NOT presented or used.

You need to write a delegate or a callback to pass the chosen country code to your original DisplayCountryVC.

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot that i was dismissing to the original VC not presenting it! I fixed this problem thanks to this. thank you so much :)